# What is python's equivalent of R's writeBin()?

Tags: python, r, encode

I need to create a BLOB in python. In R generally numeric vector is converted using `writeBin` and then (optinally) compressed using `memCompress`. What would the process be in python?

```
x = c(1.0, 2.5)
writeBin(x, raw(), size = NA_real_)
# 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 40
memCompress(writeBin(x, raw(), size = NA_real_), "gzip")
# 78 9c 63 60 00 81 0f f6 60 8a 81 c5 01 00 0b ef 01 74
```

Comment: Is that really the "gzip" option output? That's a zlib stream.

Comment: Right! I think the function named zlib compression as gzip. These are the legacy issues with R

Comment: At any rate, have a look at the struct module in Python https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: Regarding the header string for gzip, In the documentation they say RFC 1950 format is followed